# Satellite menu: Animation works only once

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, menu

I'm using the [Sattelite Menu](https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu) in my android app.

I've included it as my project, added the following XML and Java and the app works just fine, no errors.

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:sat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android.view.ext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.view.ext.SatelliteMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" 
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        sat:satelliteDistance="170dp"
        sat:mainImage="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        sat:totalSpacingDegree="90"
        sat:closeOnClick="true"
        sat:expandDuration="500"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

and Java:

```
SatelliteMenu menu = (SatelliteMenu) findViewById(R.id.menu);
    List<SatelliteMenuItem> items = new ArrayList<SatelliteMenuItem>();
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(3, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(2, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    items.add(new SatelliteMenuItem(1, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

The app starts, with the little menu icon in the bottom left corner, as expected. Click it and little buttons pop out with a fancy animation. Click it again, the menu closes and the buttons go back with another fancy animation.

**The Problem begins..** Now, when I click it again (3rd time), there is no animation this time. The buttons simply appear in their correct places (and still work) but they don't fly out. For some reason the animation does not gets started.

I've tried to look at the source and this should not be happening. Even the sample app works perfect. But when I implemented it in my own app, the animation just works the first time when I open the menu.

What could be causing this?

Thank you!

EDIT: This solution too doesn't work. It didn't do anything :/

```
private void onClick() {
    if (plusAnimationActive.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        if (!rotated) {
            resetItems();
            imgMain.startAnimation(mainRotateLeft);
            for (SatelliteMenuItem item : menuItems) {
                item.getView().startAnimation(item.getOutAnimation());
            }
        } else {
            resetItems();
            imgMain.startAnimation(mainRotateRight);
            for (SatelliteMenuItem item : menuItems) {
                item.getView().startAnimation(item.getInAnimation());
            }
        }
        rotated = !rotated;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Layout Animations are run when views are added to the layout. So you will have to manually add/remove the views on every expand/collapse for the layout animation to work.

Comment: But the menu uses a lot of animations with only one option to add animations (menu.startanimation) ... If I use clear animations that too changes nothing... How exactly are you suggesting I fix this?

Comment: In SatelliteMenu class, we have onClick method for imgMain. In that before calling startAnimation( both if and else conditions) just call resetItems().

Comment: Kindly see my edit, is that what you were talking about? I'm afraid that didn't do it :/

Comment: ok. Otherwise use imgMain.clearAnimation() instead of resetItems().

Comment: I have tried everything, I noticed that it works perfectly on the emulator too. Perhaps, it's a problem with my device... :/ Any ideas?